# Methods for embedding Wordpress into Matrix?

Tags: wordpress, matrix, mysource

How can you embed Wordpress into Squiz Matrix? Not necessarily the whole instance, maybe just elements that will make life easier.

I was thinking about iframing but that seemed a little outdated - has anyone made a custom asset which allows you to use Wordpress? If not that should really be added Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can iframe the wordpress site in

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a remote content asset.

Documentation on how to use remote content assets can be found [here](http://manuals.matrix.squizsuite.net/remote-content).